# "derby dialect has been deprecated"

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I am getting an error while I'm trying to perform simple sql transaction in hibernate. I am using hibernate 4.3, it says `derby dialect has been deprecated`

I tried to google and I found that I need version-specific dialect. Can you please tell me where and how can i get it?

you may want to see the error log  from :

[image]         .

Can anyone tell me what should i do ?

Comment: Please don't provide information as image which can be text.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using **Spring Boot** just add to your **application.properties**:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
```

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate provides specialized Dialect classes that inherit from `DerbyDialect`. If you check the class hierarchy, you will see that there are dialects

```
DerbyTenFiveDialect
DerbyTenSixDialect
DerbyTenSevenDialect
```

all in the same package as the `DerbyDialect` class. Just use the dialect according to your Derby version.